# Use of GridLayout from support library leads to 'NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection'

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I am using GridLayout in my app and it works perfectly. Now I have to support android 3.xx as well, so I included android-support-library-v7. I just changed the import statements for GridLayout and LayoutParams at all places. I can build the project now but when I run the app, it crashes with NoSuchMethodError exception.

I followed these [steps to include the support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Here is the stacktrace:

```
    03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.isLayoutRtlCompat(GridLayout.java:675)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.getDefaultMargin(GridLayout.java:660)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.getMargin1(GridLayout.java:671)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeMargins(GridLayout.java:1547)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getLeadingMargins(GridLayout.java:1558)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.getMargin(GridLayout.java:683)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.getTotalMargin(GridLayout.java:692)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.measureChildWithMargins2(GridLayout.java:897)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.measureChildrenWithMargins(GridLayout.java:911)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:950)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1229)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:301)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1918)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1843)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1333)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
03-27 13:37:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.perfor
```

EDIT: code

```
public class TableRenderingView extends GridLayout{

    private Context mContext;


    public TableRenderingView(Context context){
        super(context);
        mContext = context; 
        setUseDefaultMargins(true);
        setAlignmentMode(ALIGN_BOUNDS);
        setRowOrderPreserved(false);        
    }
...

}
```

Exception occurs when I try to add this extended class dynamically inside a LinearLayout

```
TableRenderingView trv = new TableRenderingView(context);
                View v = trv.populate(gridRowData);
                LinearLayout ll = ((LinearLayout) tableContainerView.getChildAt(0));
                ll.removeAllViews();
                ll.addView(v);
```

Comment: Can you also please post the code ?

Comment: The code is spanned across classes. When I instantiate the GridLayout am getting this exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this was happening because the android-support-v4 library that my project was referring to was older than the latest available. Since we have to copy android-support-v4.jar library manually into our project's /libs folder, no matter how many times you update the sdk, it will have little impact until we manually overwrite support library .jar thats there in the project folder.

Where I went wrong? I was under the impression that I have the latest android-support-v4.jar in my project directory. Since all my attempts to solve this issue by changing the build path and order failed, as a final resort I overwritted my android-support-v4.jar in the project /libs with one in the /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar. Voila it started working.

And this is how I added support-v7 gridlayout into my project

1. Copy 'gridlayout' folder from '\extras\android\support\v7' to location where your android project is located
2. Import the library copied in step1 as android-library into workspace
3. Reference the imported library from step2 on your android application

Note:

1. After the above steps are performed check 'android-support-v7-gridlayour.jar' is  included under 'Android Dependencies' under your android application project.
2. Check a new line is added for 'gridlayout' project in your android application's  'project.properties'. In my case the below line was added

   ```
    android.library.reference.1=../gridlayout
   ```
3. Apart from the above mentioned steps I did not follow any other steps mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#)

Comment: Replacing my old android-support-v4.jar with the latest solved it for me. I am unfortunately required to use IntelliJ without Gradle support for this project, so dependency management is a **huge** pain in the a$$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both `android-support-v4` and `android-support-v13` you need also update v13. This was my case. I have updated **`v4`** to the latest version but still was getting the **error**:

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.hasOnClickListeners**.

I have noticed Eclipse's message in console: "WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list. Because `v13` includes `v4`, using only v13".

So I have copied new version of the **\sdk\extras\android\support\v13\android-support-v13.jar** to my project's `libs` folder (have replaced old version) and the error has gone.

**Conclusion:** we should probably update all support libraries are used in our projects at once.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in Xamarin Studio. I resolved it by doing these steps:

1. Clean all Projects in Debug Configuration.
2. Clean all Projects in Release Configuration.
3. Manually deleted the packages folder in the project. (Deleting all Nuget packages).
4. Rebooted the
   computer.
5. Run the project again.