# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.hasAccessibilityDelegate

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I made an android app, but it is not working on some devices, 
such as Samsung Galaxy SM-G9008W and Sony L36H. On other devices it is ok.

I used the RecyclerView in Android support v7. The problem is no method is found, but I put it to the project. Here is the error info.

I searched the error info by Google, but there were no results.

thank you, @Sarah Elan~

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.hasAccessibilityDelegate
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getScrapList(Unknown Source)
                                                getViewForPosition
                                                quickRecycleScrapView
                                                unscrapView
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.hasMore(Unknown Source)
                                                          next
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onDetachedFromWindow(Unknown Source)
                                              onInitializeAccessibilityEvent
                                              onRestoreInstanceState
                                              setOrientation
                                              onAnchorReady
                                              fixLayoutEndGap
                                              updateLayoutStateToFillEnd
                                              scrollHorizontallyBy
                                              computeHorizontalScrollOffset
                                              updateLayoutState
                                              assertNotInLayoutOrScroll
                                              recycleChildren
                                              recycleByLayoutState
                                              fill
                                              layoutChunk
                                              findReferenceChild
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onDetachedFromWindow(Unknown Source)
                                              onInitializeAccessibilityEvent
                                              onRestoreInstanceState
                                              setOrientation
                                              onAnchorReady
                                              fixLayoutEndGap
                                              updateLayoutStateToFillEnd
                                              scrollHorizontallyBy
                                              computeHorizontalScrollOffset
                                              updateLayoutState
                                              assertNotInLayoutOrScroll
                                              recycleChildren
                                              recycleByLayoutState
                                              fill
                                              layoutChunk
                                              findReferenceChild
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(Unknown Source)
                                              computeHorizontalScrollExtent
                                              onFocusSearchFailed$1539f5dc
                                              supportsPredictiveItemAnimations
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setScrollState(Unknown Source)
                                       dispatchLayout
                                       offsetPositionRecordsForInsert
                                       getItemDecorInsetsForChild
                                       access$502$767d6395
                                       access$4400
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:2037)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2071)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1256)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6649)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *i search error info by Google,but has not result* ... bs ... yes, there is a plenty similar questions ... also: you could provide information what have you tried so far ...  also: where are versions!!! .... **edit:** from first link from infu-credible simple searching:  *So this was happening because the android-support-v4 library that my project was referring to was older than the latest available.*

Comment: sorry, the lib code is API 21, all libs new. i updated the libs. but it is not work~

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok after i read this question: 
[NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681691/use-of-gridlayout-from-support-library-leads-to-nosuchmethoderror-android-supp)

So, i update the android-support-library-v7-RecyclerView and android-support-library-v4 to r22, before is r21. 
but i can't to test it. because it's working in my devices;